# Let $\mathcal{F_1}$ and $\mathcal{F_2}$ be two $\sigma-$algebras of subsets of $\Omega$. Write the definition of $\mathcal{F_1} \cap \mathcal{F_2}$:

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $\mathcal{F_1}$ and $\mathcal{F_2}$ be two $\sigma-$algebras of subsets of $\Omega$. Write the definition of $\mathcal{F_1} \cap \mathcal{F_2}$, and show that $\mathcal{F_1} \cap \mathcal{F_2}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra.

Definition: $\mathcal{F_1} \cap \mathcal{F_2}=\{A\subset \Omega | A\in \mathcal{F_1}\: \text{and}\: A\in \mathcal{F_2}\}$

1. Since $\mathcal{F_1}$ and $\mathcal{F_2}$ are two $\sigma-$algebras, then $\Omega \in \mathcal{F_1}$ and $\Omega \in \mathcal{F_2}$, by definition $\Omega \in \mathcal{F_1} \cap \mathcal{F_2}$.
2. Let $A \in \mathcal{F_1} \cap \mathcal{F_2}$, then $A\in\mathcal{F_1}$ and $A\in\mathcal{F_2}$. Since $\mathcal{F_1}$ and $\mathcal{F_2}$ are $\sigma-$algebras, then $A^c\in\mathcal{F_1}$ and $A^c\in\mathcal{F_2}$, i.e. $A^c\in\mathcal{F_1 \cap F_2}$.
3. Let $A_1, A_2,\ldots \in \mathcal{F_1 \cap F_2}$, then $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}\in \mathcal{F_1}$ and $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}\in \mathcal{F_2}$, i.e. $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} A_{i}\in \mathcal{F_1\cap F_2}$.

Therefore, $\mathcal{F_1\cap F_2}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra.

Is this okay?

Comment: This is correct, but you didn't actually "write the definition of $\mathcal F_1 \cap \mathcal F_2$."

Comment: @user6247850 Definition: $\mathcal{F_1} \cap \mathcal{F_2}=\{A\subset \Omega | A\in \mathcal{F_1}\: \text{and}\: A\in \mathcal{F_2}\}$

Comment: Yeah, you clearly knew what it was and used it.  Now everything is correct and complete.